# Check if a program (Slack) is installed on a system?

Tags: windows, powershell

I would like to check whether Slack is installed on a system or not.

Even though it was installed both of the below two commands giving me blank, why is this?

System details are: Windows 10 64 bit.

```
$slack32 = Get-ItemProperty 'HKLM:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\*' |
           Select-Object DisplayName |
           Select-String "Slack" |
           Out-String

$slack64 = Get-ItemProperty 'HKLM:\Software\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\*' |
           Select-Object DisplayName |
           Select-String "Slack" |
           Out-String
```

Comment: Is it only a typo on the question that you forgot the `|` before the `Select-Object`? If not, this is probaly the cause of your troubles.

Comment: @Paxz That typo happened only at the time of writing in stakoverflow. even with  | before the Select-Object   it is giving blank.

Comment: Is slack only 32-bit? Are you executing the `$slack32` line in a 32-bit console?

Comment: @ Lieven Keersmaekers No slack has separate installer for  64 bit and 32 bit also. i installed 64 bit one. i tried on both 32 bit and 64 bit console. both are giving blank only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Slack by default installs under the User's directory, not Program Files, probably does the same in the registry hives.
Try `HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\*`

Comment: Checked and for me this reg location is correct for Slack.

Comment: I got blank when i run the following command.  what exactly you are getting the value for $32BIT.                                                                                            $32BIT = "HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\*" |  Select-Object DisplayName | select-string "slack" | out-string

Comment: it is working fine with ....   $slack32 = Get-ItemProperty 'HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\*' | Select-Object DisplayName | Select-String "Slack" | Out-String